# Check same value in multiple lists [python]

Tags: python, list

I've 5 lists with some Infos saved in like:

```
list1 = [['Mark',18],['Lola',29]]
list2 = [['James' 33],['Mark',46]]
list3 = [['Lola',86],['Arnold',78]]
list4 = [['James',46],['Arnold',18]]
list5 = [['Mark',16], ['James',10]]
```

What i'd like do is check them and create a table like that's:

```
Name    Score1  Score2  Score3
----    ------- ------- --------
Mark     18      46      16
Lola     29      86
Arnold   78      18
James    33      46      10
```

I've no worries to import a new library like pandas or others.

I tried to use some nested For loop to check if there's double values in each list and if was true, add it, but i've many trouble to get the by name (ex. List['James']) After some research seems that's Is not possibile to do in py.

Looking for any kind of solition to understand better.

Comment: I will provide to put some code editing the post. I made a mistake for dont posting Before. Sorry Pranav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import chain

list1 = [["Mark", 18], ["Lola", 29]]
list2 = [["James", 33], ["Mark", 46]]
list3 = [["Lola", 86], ["Arnold", 78]]
list4 = [["James", 46], ["Arnold", 18]]
list5 = [["Mark", 16], ["James", 10]]


tmp = {}
for name, score in chain.from_iterable([list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]):
    tmp.setdefault(name, []).append(score)

max_scores = len(max(tmp.values(), key=len))

print(
    "{:<15}".format("Name")
    + ("{:<10}" * max_scores).format(
        *[f"Score{i+1}" for i in range(max_scores)]
    )
)

print(
    "{:<15}".format("-" * 4)
    + ("{:<10}" * max_scores).format(*["-" * 6 for _ in range(max_scores)])
)

for k, v in tmp.items():
    print("{:<15}".format(k), end="")
    print(("{:<10}" * len(v)).format(*[str(i) for i in v]))
```

Prints:

```
Name           Score1    Score2    Score3    
----           ------    ------    ------    
Mark           18        46        16        
Lola           29        86        
James          33        46        10        
Arnold         78        18
```

Answer (score 0):

I **would not recommend** to store data in this way, i.e. dictionary can be a good solution for this situation. Anyway, if we assume, that you get this result from somewhere else, then you can do something like this:

```
scores = dict()
for i, lst in enumerate((list1, list2, list3, list4, list5), start=1):
    for record in lst:
        player_scores = scores.get(record[0], {})
        player_scores[i] = record[1]
        scores[record[0]] = player_scores
```

Then you can easily print from this dict or use in any other parts.

**P.S.** And yes, I don't like the look of the enumerate, too )